# Return the sum of the array with decimal numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes the array of score and needs to calculate the average score. This works with regular numbers, but doesn't work when the score number has a decimal. How do I change this function to solve this? We don't want to cut the decimals of course.

```
const score = [ "3.0", "3.2", "4.4" ]

const result = (survey
        .map( function(i){ // assure the value can be converted into an integer
        return /^\d+$/.test(i) ? parseInt(i) : 0; 
      })
      .reduce( function(a,b){ // sum all resulting numbers
        return (a+b) 
      })/score.length).toFixed(1)
```

Comment: use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: Also, future-proof yourself and use `Number.parseFloat` instead of the global `parseFloat`.

Comment: You should use `Number(i)`. That handles integers and floats. You'd need to change your regular expression to `\d+(\.\d+)?` though

Comment: There is no need to loop the array twice, you can parse the numbers inside `reduce`. BTW you can also use the unary `+` to implicitly convert the strings into numbers. Shorter code `const result = score.reduce((sum, n) => sum + +n, 0) / score.length;`

Comment: A compact solution would be: `score.reduce((sum,x) => sum + (Number(x) || 0), 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I barely changed your code. Adjusted the regex and used parseFloat.

```js
const score = ["3.0", "3.2", "4.4"]

const result = (score
  .map(function(i) { // assure the value can be converted into an integer
    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(i) ? parseFloat(i) : 0;
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) { // sum all resulting numbers
    return (a + b)
  }) /
  score.length).toFixed(1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use recursion:

```
function sum(a) {
  return (a.length && parseFloat(a[0]) + sum(a.slice(1))) || 0;
}

sum([ "3.0", "3.2", "4.4" ]).toFixed(1); // 10.6
```